# What are industry averages for percentage of certified PM's?

Tags: team-management

I run the PMO for an IT organization with ~1,200 people and 120 PMs.  What are industry averages for the % of project managers with industry certifications (PMP, ACM, etc.)?  Thanks.

Comment: Which industry?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with trying to understand the prevalence of the PMP or any other project certification is the denominator.  I think the relevant organizations publish the number of certified practitioners but I am not sure how you could find out the number of people who are managing projects.  Would it be the number of people who have PM as a title or can it include those who manage projects or sub projects as a role?  Would it include those who specialize in project controls?

The more important question to your question is why?  Do you consider a project certificate as a valid indicator of future performance?  Or do you use the certificate as a selling point for work proposals?  Whatever your belief is about the efficacy of certificates in this business, I do not know if anyone could ever argue the existence of some optimal ratio between certified and non certified practitioners.

A more reasonable discussion would be around why you may want some prevalence of certificates in your organization.  If to advertise in your proposals, the certs do sell.  If you think it predicts future performance, you'd be best serve to look for studies that might substantiate that belief because there is not a lot out there that would support a certificate's validity.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen much out there that talks about exact numbers but there is some useful information on the state of the PM profession as a whole in the PMI's ['Pulse of the Profession'](http://www.pmi.org/Knowledge-Center/Pulse/Pulse-Key-Findings.aspx) report.

Specific to your question the [PMI say](http://www.pmi.org/uk-landing.aspx) that of organisations reporting 'more project success' than their counterparts 69% report that 35% of the PM staff are [PMP](http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx) qualified. Now, that only covers PMP so it doesn't give you an overall figure (and PMI aren't likely to be shouting about the prevalence/successes of rival qualifications) but it is an indicator that a fairly small number of PMs *on successful projects* actually have a top certification (in this case 35% of 69% of orgs who are in the 62% reporting success). And success should really be the key here. If you're just interested in having *x*% certified PMs on your team because that's what everyone else in the industry does that's fine. But for me what matters is whether that certification has any measurable, positive impact. The report I mentioned above has some some stats that I think are far more revealing:

> training and development in project management has declined since 2010. Fewer organizations are
>   providing training on project management tools and techniques (from 65
>   percent in 2010 to 59 percent in 2012). Less than half have a process
>   to develop project management competency (45 percent, down from 52
>   percent in 2010) or have a process to mature existing project
>   management practices (44 percent, down from 51 percent in 2010).

Improving on those industry figures would, I think, lead to a healthier, happier and more successful PMO. Some of the career development/training may well result in staff becoming certified but I don't think that should be the ends in itself.